# How Do I Add PostgreSQL DataSource To Java Spring REST API Project?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, rest, gradle

I am currently developing a java spring REST API using gradle, and I just can't figure out where to declare my postgresql datasource or how to even do it. Every example I have found on google is with maven and not with gradle. Is there any example code I can look at, because I am not sure how to declare my datasource at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can a connection pooling solution like BoneCP. With BoneCP you can define a pooled Datasource and inject the datasource into your DAO's. With BoneCP you can define a bean like this

```
<bean id="bonecpDs" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource"
    lazy-init="true" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverclassname}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.connection.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes" value="${db.idleconnectiontestperiod}" />
    <property name="idleMaxAgeInMinutes" value="${db.idlemaxage}" />
    <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="${db.poolsize}" />
    <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="${db.minpoolsize}" />
    <property name="partitionCount" value="${db.numpools}" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${db.acquireincrement}" />
    <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="${db.releasehelperthreads}" />
    <property name="statementReleaseHelperThreads" value="${db.statementreleasehelperthreads}" />
    <property name="disableConnectionTracking" value="${db.disableconnectiontracking}" />
    <property name="closeConnectionWatch" value="${db.closedconnnectionwatch}" />
    <property name="connectionTimeoutInMs" value="${db.connectiontimeout}" />
    <property name="connectionTestStatement" value="select now()" />
    <property name="lazyInit" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

These are possible properties it takes. You can skip the optional ones and provide your driverClass, jdbc url, uname and password.

This bean can then be used into your DAO's as follows

```
Connection con = bonecpDs.getConnection();
```

Comment: So what file should I put this in because ATM I have no xml files since I'm using grade so what should I call it and where should I place it. Also, will grade detect this xml file automatically?

Comment: How are you defining your spring beans

Comment: I'm not, which is the problem...im assuming thats why my thing doesnt even run. How would I do it?

Comment: You can follow this url to get an idea [SpringGradle](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/gradle-spring-mvc-web-project-example/)

Comment: BoneCP is deprecated. Use HikariCP.